# Reuse RTK Query endpoints as a package in a monorepo

Tags: package, shared-libraries, monorepo, rtk-query

Has anyone had any luck using RTK Query as a shared package in a Monorepo?

We have a number of front end applications that all query the same API and are looking to extract our endpoints and interfaces to a shared package, while injecting the `baseUrl` or `baseQuery`.

The issue I'm facing is how to manage this when using code splitting and `injectEndpoints`, where the endpoints are initially empty upon creating the api and are then injected in other files that import the created api.

I can wrap the `createApi` method in another method, passing the in the `baseQuery` or `baseUrl`, but I can't get my head around how to make this play nicely with code splitting as shown here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting

Comment: do you find any solution over this couple of month?

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this solution that it works for me.

after create an `api` package folder in packages directory with `src` folder inside of it you can create and `apiSlice.js` in `src` folder like this.

```
api
---src
----auth
-------index.js
----apislice.js
----index.js
---rollup.config.js
---package.json
```

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export default createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({})
});
```

then define other `apis` (code spliting) in different file like this`:

```
export const AuthApi = {
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        logOut: builder.mutation({
            query: () => ({
                url: `/auth/login`,
                method: 'post'
            }),
            transformErrorResponse: (response, meta, arg) => ({
                response: response.data,
                meta,
                arg
            })
        })
    })
};
```

after that i create an `index.js` file in `src` folder like this:

```
import ApiSlice from 'apiSlice';
import { AuthApi } from 'auth'

ApiSlice.injectEndpoints(AuthApi);
```

then in the root of api package create `rollup.config.js` like so:

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import dotenv from 'rollup-plugin-dotenv';

export default {
    input: './src/index.js',
    output: [
        {
            file: 'dist/index.js',
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true,
            exports: 'named'
        },
        {
            file: 'dist/index.es.js',
            format: 'esm',
            sourcemap: true,
            exports: 'named'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        resolve({
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        }),
        dotenv(),
        babel({
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            babelHelpers: 'bundled',
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        terser()
    ]
};
```

`rollup-plugin-dotenv` will read your env file and replace the actual data in your bundle.

after you build it you will be able to use it in different project that use the same api.

and here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^4.9.5",
    "rollup-plugin-dotenv": "^0.5.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.5"
  }
}
```

and finally in your store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
import ApiSlice from 'api'; // ==> we default export before

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [ApiSlice.reducerPath]: ApiSlice.reducer
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(ApiSlice.middleware)
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

i don't know it is a best practice or not. import all endpoints into index file and run injectEndpoints on them is not a good idea i guess.