# Use RTK Query endpoints as a package in a lerna monorepo

Tags: redux, monorepo, rtk-query, lerna, nx-monorepo

I have Lerna Monorepo with an `api` folder inside of the `packages` folder.

`api` folder is just RTKQuery endpoints which code split into several other folders as described in [Code Splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting).

I have two other React apps. one for website and the other for admin panel.

currently what I do is this:

```
import { useAdminSampleQuery } from 'api/admin/sampleQuery';
import { useSampleQuery } from 'api/sampleQuery';
```

and I need to use RTK query in those apps like so:

```
import { useAdminSampleQuery, useSampleQuery } from 'api';
```

so I tried to use rollup and simply combine all the files into one, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159488/how-to-configure-in-rollup-that-will-generate-only-single-output-file-from-multi) problem.

I just need to use the whole RTKquery folder as a separate package any solutions? [same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998377/reuse-rtk-query-endpoints-as-a-package-in-a-monorepo)]